# How can give info only once with QMessageBox while internet connection is OFF?

Tags: python, pyqt5

this code opens web site with Qt browser. If internet connection is lost I want to give Information message with QMessageBox:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication as App
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QWindow
from PyQt5 import QtNetwork, QtCore, QtWidgets
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import threading
import time

class WebApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_connected = None
        self.is_msgshow = True
        self.msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "OZI"
        self.t_internet = threading.Thread(target=self.is_internet)
        self.t_internet.start()
        self.t_refreshpage = threading.Thread(target=self.refresh_page)
        self.t_refreshpage.start()
        self.web = QWebEngineView()
        self.web.window().setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
        self.web.showFullScreen()

    def is_internet(self):
        """
        Query internet using python
        :return:
        """
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                urlopen("http://www.google.com", timeout=1)
                self.is_connected = True
            except urllib.error.URLError as Error:
                print(Error)
                self.is_connected = False
            print(self.is_connected)

    def refresh_page(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
            if self.is_connected == False:
                time.sleep(5)
                if self.is_connected == True:
                    self.web.page().action(QWebEnginePage.Reload).trigger()
                else:
                    if self.is_msgshow == True:
                        print('testtt')
                        self.msg.information(None, 'INFO', 'PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION!!!')
                        self.is_msgshow = False
                        self.msg.close()
            else:
                pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = WebApp()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, I couldn't succeed at

```
                 if self.is_msgshow == True:
                    print('testtt')
```

this part while internet connection is lost my code opens many MessageBox. I guess my fault is controlling self.is_msgshow flag.

Answer (score 1):

Far beyond the problem you are pointing out, you have other errors and it is more dangerous than the one indicated: You should not access the GUI from another thread, and you should also not access the same variable from 2 threads without protecting it through a mutex, semaphore or Similary. For example, you are calling `self.web.page().action(QWebEnginePage.Reload).trigger()` and `self.msg.information(None, 'INFO', 'PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION!!!')` from the secondary thread, and the variable "is_connected" is accessed by several threads.

Another error is that method `QMessage::information()` is static and generates a new object that is not directly accessible, instead you must use the object "self.msg" through its own methods to display the necessary information.

Considering the above I have created a class that is only responsible for analyzing the status of the connection and if it changes to emit a signal. To send information between threads in Qt you can use signals or `QMetaObject::invokedMethod()` in addition to the classic mutex and semaphores.

Then it is only necessary to analyze the value of the status sent to the GUI to implement the logic:

```py
import sys
import threading
import time

import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtNetwork, QtWebEngineWidgets


class ConnectivityManager(QtCore.QObject):
    statusChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, *, timeout=4000, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._status = False

        self._timeout = timeout

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._check, daemon=True).start()

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool, notify=statusChanged)
    def status(self):
        return self._status

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def _update_status(self, status):
        if self._status != status:
            self._status = status
            self.statusChanged.emit(self.status)

    def _check(self):
        while True:
            try:
                urlopen("http://www.google.com", timeout=1)
                status = True
            except urllib.error.URLError as Error:
                status = False
            QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(
                self,
                "_update_status",
                QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
                QtCore.Q_ARG(bool, status),
            )
            time.sleep(5)


class WebApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("OZI")
        self.web = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.web)
        self.web.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.connectivity_manager = ConnectivityManager()
        self.connectivity_manager.statusChanged.connect(self.on_status_changed)
        self.connectivity_manager.start()

        self.msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("INFO")
        self.msg.setText("PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION!!!")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_status_changed(self, status):
        if status:
            self.msg.hide()
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Connected")
            self.web.page().action(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.Reload).trigger()
        else:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Disconnected")
            self.msg.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WebApp()
    ex.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On the other hand, the same logic can be implemented using QtNetwork without the need for threads:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtNetwork, QtWebEngineWidgets


class ConnectivityManager(QtCore.QObject):
    statusChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, *, timeout=4000, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._status = False

        self._timeout = timeout
        self.manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(
            singleShot=True, interval=self._timeout, timeout=self.verify_status
        )

    def start(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self._check)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool, notify=statusChanged)
    def status(self):
        return self._status

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def _update_status(self, status):
        if self._status != status:
            self._status = status
            self.statusChanged.emit(self.status)

    def _check(self):
        url = QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.com/")
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(url)
        self._reply = self.manager.get(req)
        self._reply.finished.connect(self.verify_status)
        self._timer.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def verify_status(self):
        if self._timer.isActive():
            self._timer.stop()
            if self._reply.error() == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
                v = self._reply.attribute(
                    QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.HttpStatusCodeAttribute
                )
                if 200 <= v < 300:
                    self._update_status(True)
                else:
                    print("error", "code error: {}".format(v))
                    self._update_status(False)
            else:
                print("error", self._reply.errorString())
                self._update_status(False)
        else:
            self._reply.finished.disconnect(self.verify_status)
            self._reply.abort()
            print("Timeout")
            self._update_status(False)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, self._check)
        self._reply.deleteLater()


class WebApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("OZI")
        self.web = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.web)
        self.web.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.connectivity_manager = ConnectivityManager()
        self.connectivity_manager.statusChanged.connect(self.on_status_changed)
        self.connectivity_manager.start()

        self.msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("INFO")
        self.msg.setText("PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION!!!")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_status_changed(self, status):
        if status:
            self.msg.hide()
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Connected")
            self.web.page().action(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.Reload).trigger()
        else:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Disconnected")
            self.msg.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WebApp()
    ex.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much you explained very well. I understand my faults. However I didn't understand some parts of your codes. Such as how pyqtSlot() decorator effects first code that you shared ? and How pyqtsignal understands my internet connection?? again big thanks for your help.

Comment: @OzanSezer 1) pyqtSlot is a decorator that gives certain magic powers to the methods of the QObject: For example, if it is connected to a signal that is used in another thread, it ensures that this method is executed in the thread where the QObject was created and in this case It is necessary to avoid the problems that you point out. 2) The signals are elements that carry information between the objects, in this case a ConnectivityManager object sends information on the connection status (only when the state changes).

Comment: @OzanSezer  In a GUI, you should avoid time-consuming loops and work with events: That is, if something different happens, something must be done in the GUI, if there are no changes, nothing is done.

Comment: I understand that  instead of using decorators I can use threads or other functions but it consumes more energy and time is it right ??

Comment: @OzanSezer read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator

Comment: @OzanSezer The problem with your code is that you do not know how to handle threads (I recommend you review multithreading problems such as managing shared resources). If you check the above you will see that unnecessary complexity is added that can be avoided using the signals in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the pyqt5 at all but guessing by flow of your code, here:

```
if self.is_msgshow == True:
    print('testtt')
    self.msg.information(None, 'INFO', 'PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION!!!')
    self.is_msgshow = False
    self.msg.close()
```

It seems the `self.msg.information()` call is expected to be **synchronous**. If that is so, then as long as it remains open, the `is_msgshow` is still `True` because you changing it once you got dialog closed. And this is your bug as if new even occurs then nothing blocks new dialog from being shown. The fix is pretty simple - just move `self.is_msgshow = False` to be very first thing done in that code block, you should be good:

```
if self.is_msgshow:
    self.is_msgshow = False
    print('testtt')
    self.msg.information(None, 'INFO', 'PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION!!!')
    self.msg.close()
```

Additional note, you may want to reset it back to `True` once connectivity is restored otherwise you won't show a thing next time network is down.

> The QMessageBox class provides a **modal** dialog for informing the user or for asking the user a question and receiving an answer.

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QMessageBox.html